# How to disable specific control in audio player HTML5

Tags: html, css, html5-audio

I just want to show the audio controls but prohibits the user to drag the button because I don't want the user to skip the song. How to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. You either show the browser's builtin controls, or you don't.

So what you should so is hide them and make your own (it should be easy if you don't want the seek functionality) or look at something like jPlayer (http://jplayer.org/) and hide the seek bar with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there's currently (August 2015) still no standard way to hide specific controls in a clean way. The best way to handle this is by using a library for this. E.g. one of these:

- http://buzz.jaysalvat.com/
- http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/
- http://jplayer.org/
- http://mediaelementjs.com/