# How to hide position slider in HTML5 audio tag? Hide "fake" input element inside audio element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-audio, audio-streaming

I have built an internet radio at [radio.meteor.com](http://radio.meteor.com/) (code at [GitHub](https://github.com/guaka/radio-meteor/)). I'm using an HTML5 audio tag.

```
<audio preload id="player" controls>
  <source src="{{srcUrl}}" />
</audio>
```

[link to source](https://github.com/guaka/radio-meteor/blob/6dea5af6b244c7502f8a56073b20ac729c721bcb/client/player.html#L11)

[image: audio element]

Since it's only playing streams there's no point in the slider showing up. Is there a good way to hide the slide? Ideally not by putting another div on top to make the entire area black.

In Chrome it even seems like there's an input element inside the audio element. Isn't there a way to hide this input element? Would be great even if it only works inside Chrome.

[image: input element pops up inside audio tag]

(Yes, this question is somewhat duplicate of [How to disable specific control in audio player HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19090927/how-to-disable-specific-control-in-audio-player-html5) - but that question is a lot less precise and this question is more useful to both people and more likely to be found.)

---

(Question is closed so I can't add this as an answer:)

August 2015 there's still no clean way to do this. These are some useful libraries:

- http://buzz.jaysalvat.com/
- http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/
- http://jplayer.org/
- http://mediaelementjs.com/

Comment: could you show the html code?

Comment: Added HTML code, with deeplink to source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't hide the slide unfortunately. I played with this for a voicemail app recently and ended up listening to the events emitted by the `<audio ..>` element and writing my own display. If you don't include `controls` it's not displayed (although I hid it explicitly too with css).

MDN docs:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio

Here is a simple example of one approach... HTML

```
<audio controls src="http://developer.mozilla.org/@api/deki/files/2926/=AudioTest_(1).ogg" autoplay>
  Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> element.
</audio>
<br/>
Current Time: <span id="currentTime"></span>s
```

JS

```
var v = document.getElementsByTagName("audio")[0];
v.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() { 
  document.getElementById('currentTime').innerHTML = Math.floor(v.currentTime);
}, true);
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r9exn16d/